# Send Data using Raspberry Pi's Serial Number

Tags: serial, data-transfer, pi-3b+

Actually I have many Raspberry PI 3 Model B and I am able to find Serial Number of my Raspberry PI using Python script. But I can't able to send data from Cloud to specific Raspberry PI using it's Serial Number.

**Is there any way to send data from another device to Raspberry PI using Raspberry PI's Serial Number ?**

Any Suggestions/Links would be Thankful.

Comment: Wouldn't IP address be easier?

Comment: @Steve that's true. But I have Mobile Application to control my Smart devices remotely from anywhere. For that i have one central Raspberry PI that control all other devices. So how can i distinguish my PI from every other. Suppose you also want to control your smart devices using same App than how could application distinguish between our PI ? For that every user need Unique static ID like MAC address. And Serial Number is more secure then MAC address because serial number is include MAC address too.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi serial number has no relationship to an address on the internet.  The cloud rather implies the internet.

Comment: you'd need the pi to register it's IP with it's serial number on some server, then you can lookup the serial number and send to that IP

Comment: @Joan you are right. I tried in 3 Raspberry PI and i get every-time last 6 digits as MAC address of the PI. Secondly i thought, that I get Serial Number by using Python script then i can use those number as a unique key for transmitting and receiving data from Cloud. Don't you think so ?

Comment: @Jaromanda Yes. For that we need to use DDNS and static IP with Port forwarding and again I have Problem of Privacy. That the sever can access my data. Secondly I have common Mobile Application in other hand so it might be hard to use.

Comment: How do you want to get any info (as e.g. serial number) whilst you are not connected to the raspberry pi? What makes you believe that using the mac address is unsecure (or more unsecure than what you will do)? To me it sounds like you are trying to implement a functionality that allready exists (like wpa-handshake, etc.), or did I get you wrong?

Comment: if you have DDNS you don't need a static IP ... and yes, of course you'll need port forwarding for something on the internet to connect to something in your LAN - regardless of what you use (IP or serial number or whatever)

Comment: @Sim I wrote python script that's give me Serial Number of each PI and every PI has Internet Access through Ethernet cable. Anyone can spoof MAC address, in that case my data goes to different PI (via  cloud using MAC address) if someone spoof MAC address exactly same as mine. If I use Serial Number of my PI that means it's rare chance to be same because serial Number is (unique Number + MAC address). And as Jaromanda said, I have to lookup my serial Number with MAC address on Cloud than i get info about Serial Number.